# Loading dataset from external file system (https) directly into Spark dataframe

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm trying to load a CSV dataset directly from an external file system, but I'm getting a 401 Unauthorized response whenever I call sparkContext.addFile(). Is there a way to add authorization headers to the request before adding the file? Or a better way to load a csv file as a dataframe?

This is what I'm trying now and it throws an exception when I make the addFile() call.

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkFiles

spark.sparkContext.addFile(urlPath)
val df = spark.read
    .option("header", true)
    .csv("file://"+SparkFiles.get(urlPath))
```

Comment: First check if you can programmatically download the file in python using `requests` or `http` lib. You are getting `401 Unauthorized` response which means the URL resource requires some kind of authentication credentials like cookies, token etc.

Comment: I do have the authentication details, I just don’t know how to pass them to the Spark config.

Comment: Can you please check this tutorial. You dont have to pass the entire url to sparkfile.get.        https://www.tutorialspoint.com/pyspark/pyspark_sparkfiles.htm